# How can I use ASANA.com on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, asana, asana-api, asana-connect

- I want to use [ASANA](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects) on Android Studio.

I entered my username and password and then entered my project number incorrectly but gave me an error

**My question is:**

1. How to connect to this service?
2. How do I use this service on Android Studio?

**This is the way to set up Asana in Android Studio:**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/auth?missingtranslation=fr#i18n-404
You can probably use a Personal Access Token from your Asana app configuration.